# How would I show a second dropdown on-hover using jquery for a PHP array?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a PHP array and I am showing a drop down of some content and want to show a second level drop down on only one of the array groups. How would I single out only one array to have a second level drop down? Here is the example: http://mmcgroup.burnseo.com/ The array and drop down I am speaking of is under "New Cars" in the main navigation. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="newcarmenu">
    <div class="ncmcontainer" group="<?= $m['tab']?>">
        <div class="ncmabsolute" onmouseover="activateInfo(this);"> <span class="ncmmodel"><?= $m['name']?></span>
            <img src="/wp-content/uploads/direct/models/<?= $m['img'] ?>"
            class="ncmimage" />
            <div class="ncminfo">
                <div class="ncmbutton">
                    <a href="<?= $m['modelPageLink'] ?>">
                        <div>MODEL INFO</div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="<?= $m['inventoryLink'] ?>">
                        <div>VIEW INVENTORY</div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="/contact">
                        <div>CONTACT US</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="floatright"> <span class="ncmmsrp">Starting MSRP:<br/><span><?= $m['msrp'] ?></span></span>
                    <div
                    class="ncmmpg">
                        <!--<span><?= $m['cmpg'] ?><br/><span style="font-size:7pt;">city</span></span><img src="/wp-content/uploads/direct/MPG.png" /><span><?= $m['hmpg'] ?><br/><span     style="font-size:7pt;">highway</span></span>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ncmexcerpt">
                <p>
                    <?=$ m[ 'excerpt'] ?>... <a href="<?= $m['modelPageLink'] ?>">Read More</a> 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
function changeGroup2(group) {
    jQuery('#newcarmenu div[class^="new"]').removeClass('activecars');
    jQuery('#newcarmenu div[class^="new"]').get(group - 1).className += ' activecars';
    jQuery('#newcarmenu .tabgroup').removeClass('activetab');
    jQuery('#newcarmenu .tabgroup').get(group - 1).className += ' activetab';
}
var i = 1;
for (j = 0; j < jQuery('#newcarmenu .ncmcontainer').length; j++) {
    if (jQuery('#newcarmenu #tempcontent').html().indexOf('div') != -1) {
        if (jQuery('#newcarmenu .new' + i + '').length == 0) {
            if (i == 1) {
                jQuery('#newcarmenu .cartabs').append('<div class="new' + i + ' activecars"></div>');
            } else {
                jQuery('#newcarmenu .cartabs').append('<div class="new' + i + '"></div>');
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                jQuery('#newcarmenu .cartab').append('<div class="tabgroup activetab" onmouseover="changeGroup2(' + i + ')">Porsche</div>')
            } else if (i == 2) {
                jQuery('#newcarmenu .cartab').append('<div class="tabgroup" onmouseover="changeGroup2(' + i + ')">Rolls-Royce</div>')
            } else if (i == 3) {
                jQuery('#newcarmenu .cartab').append('<div class="tabgroup" onmouseover="changeGroup2(' + i + ')">Bentley</div>')
            } else if (i == 4) {
                jQuery('#newcarmenu .cartab').append('<div class="tabgroup" onmouseover="changeGroup2(' + i + ')">Lamborghini</div>')
            } else if (i == 5) {
                jQuery('#newcarmenu .cartab').append('<div class="tabgroup" onmouseover="changeGroup2(' + i + ')">Lotus</div>')
            } else if (i == 6) {
                jQuery('#newcarmenu .cartab').append('<div class="tabgroup" onmouseover="changeGroup2(' + i + ')">Bugatti</div>')
            } else if (i == 7) {
                jQuery('#newcarmenu .cartab').append('<div class="tabgroup" onmouseover="changeGroup2(' + i + ')">Koenigsegg</div>')
            } else if (i == 8) {
                jQuery('#newcarmenu .cartab').append('<div class="tabgroup" onmouseover="changeGroup2(' + i + ')">Audi</div>')
            }
        }
        jQuery('#newcarmenu .new' + i + '').append(
        jQuery('#newcarmenu .ncmcontainer[group="' + i + '"]'));
        jQuery('#newcarmenu .new' + i + ' .ncmcontainer:first-child .ncminfo').addClass('activeinfo');
    }
    i++;
}
jQuery('#newcarmenu #tempcontent').remove();
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

function getModelCount($model, array $models)
{

    foreach($models as $m) {
        if ($m['model'] == $model) {
            return $m['quan'];
        }
    }

        return '0';
}

global $wpdb;

$newModels = array(
    '911' => array(
        'name' => '911',
        'inventoryLink' => '/new-cars/?make=porsche',
        'modelPageLink' => '/models/2014-porsche-911',
        'img' => '911.png',
        'tab' => 1,
        'msrp' => '$84,300',
        'cmpg' => '19',
        'hmpg' => '27',
        'excerpt' => "There are only a handful of Iconic cars on the market and Manhattan Motor Cars in NYC is proud to present the New Porsche 911 from Long Island to Manhattan and the rest     of New York. The New Porsche 911 now in the seventh generation is available in all wheel drive. The 911 Carrera coupe and the 911 Cabriolet convertible start the new NY Porsche Line     up. The Carrera has"
    ) ,
    'boxster' => array(
        'name' => 'Boxster',
        'inventoryLink' => '/new-cars/?make=porsche',
        'modelPageLink' => '/models/2014-porsche-boxster/',
        'img' => 'boxster.png',
        'tab' => 1,
        'msrp' => '$50,400',
        'cmpg' => '20',
        'hmpg' => '30',
        'excerpt' => "Since production started in 1996 a select number of drivers have joined the well known Porsche club. At Manhattan motor cars, we find the Porsche Boxster one of the     most recognizable cars on the streets of Manhattan New York. To be a part of this prestigious network is an honor here at Manhattan Motor Cars in New York City. The two seat     convertible is offered"
    ) ,
    'Cayenne' => array(
        'name' => 'Cayenne',
        'inventoryLink' => '/new-cars/?make=porsche',
        'modelPageLink' => '/models/2014-porsche-cayenne',
        'img' => 'cayenne.png',
        'tab' => 1,
        'msrp' => '$49,600',
        'cmpg' => '15',
        'hmpg' => '22',
        'excerpt' => "Our Long Island Porsche of Manhattan Motor cars has the Porsche Cayenne specific for all your needs, from the track fast turbo to fuel efficiency from a performance     SUV.  Porsche Cayenne Base comes with an enormous list of standard features for safety, performance and luxury which would suffice for the minimalist.  Eight-way power passenger     seats, power adjustable"
    )
); // end models array

$i = 0;
$j = 1;

// while($i < count($newModels)-1):

echo '<div class="cartabs"><div class="cartab"></div><div id="tempcontent">';

foreach($newModels as $k => $m):

// if($m['tab'] == $j):

?>
```

I know this can be done with a little jquery and possibly implementing a PHP array within another array. Any help would be so appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you format that so i don't have to scroll unnecessarily

Comment: he gets paid by the number of lines (regardless of what's on them)

Comment: 1980 all over again :D

Comment: But serious. From what I try to gather from your question and looking at your website, you want the dropdown (which includes the New Cars (85) to show an extended dropdown in the dropdown. You probalby want it to collapse down with another dropdown showing you that 85 new cars in a list. If that is the case, it is possible. But if you have to ask and you're using your current setup it's probably out of your reach. You will need to write a custom js dropdown'isch div with another dropdown'isch div. Needles to say, it's quite custom and to big to grasp on a website like this.

Comment: nice website though. Good use of wordpress. Although it does explain the enters. Your using a builder right? Cause if you are don't even try building something out of the box. You'll spend way to much time on it and probably without result.

Comment: Matt, thanks. It is actually the drop down in the main navigation area under "New Cars", where is shows vehicle images and more info. The drop down is only one level and I am trying to add an array that will need several vehicles. Not sure how to approach this. Possibly try to hook in to the array I want to pick and then add a new class but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.